# Sql Error : If Else with Case When in SQL

Tags: sql-server, syntax, syntax-error

Can anyone advice what is wrong here?

I got multiple syntax errors.

```
IF (('05:00' < CAST(t.Scan_In_Prod AS TIME)) AND (CAST(t.Scan_In_Prod AS TIME) < '08:00'))
BEGIN
    (CASE WHEN (CAST(t.Scan_In_Prod as TIME) < CAST(t.Scan_Out_Prod AS TIME)) AND (CAST(t.Scan_Out_Prod as TIME) < '19:00')
             THEN 'Early Out'
          WHEN ('07:00' < CAST(t.Scan_In_Prod AS TIME)) AND (CAST(t.Scan_In_Prod AS TIME) < CAST(t.Scan_In_Prod AS TIME))
             THEN 'Late In'
     END)
END
```

Errors are shown below:

> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 25
>   Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'if'.
>
> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 29
>   Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'case'.
>
> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 42
>   Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'case'.
>
> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 107
>   Incorrect syntax near 't'.

Comment: You have a `CASE` statement sitting there in isolation with no query.  This is the problem.

Comment: But the CASE has the experssion -->  (CAST(t.Scan_In_Prod as TIME) < CAST(t.Scan_Out_Prod as TIME)) and (CAST(t.Scan_Out_Prod as TIME) < '19:00')

Comment: Can advise how to amend the whole query? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NO paranthese, you should use select 
i change only

```
if (('05:00' < CAST(t.Scan_In_Prod as TIME)) and  (CAST(t.Scan_In_Prod as TIME) < '08:00'))
 begin   
 SELECT case when (CAST(t.Scan_In_Prod as TIME) < CAST(t.Scan_Out_Prod as TIME)) and (CAST(t.Scan_Out_Prod as TIME) < '19:00')
        then 'Early Out'
          when  ('07:00' < CAST(t.Scan_In_Prod as TIME)) and (CAST(t.Scan_In_Prod as TIME) < CAST(t.Scan_In_Prod as TIME))
        then 'Late In'
 end

end
```

Comment: I am glad user548682 .  can you check my answer is useful?

Answer (score 1):

Try prefacing the inner `CASE` expression with `SELECT`:

```
IF '05:00' < CAST(t.Scan_In_Prod AS TIME) AND
   '08:00' > CAST(t.Scan_In_Prod AS TIME)
BEGIN
    SELECT
        CASE WHEN CAST(t.Scan_In_Prod AS TIME) < CAST(t.Scan_Out_Prod AS TIME) AND
                  CAST(t.Scan_Out_Prod AS TIME) < '19:00'
             THEN 'Early Out'
             WHEN '07:00' < CAST(t.Scan_In_Prod AS TIME) AND
                  CAST(t.Scan_In_Prod as TIME) < CAST(t.Scan_In_Prod AS TIME)
             THEN 'Late In' END
END
```